# Match one Sec role among many roles of SecUser grails

Tags: grails

I have admin user  with  following five roles[ROLE_ADMIN,ROLESWITCHUSER,ROLE_DOCTOR,ROLE_USER]
and some **normal users** with only one  role i.e ROLE_USER ,now my question is how can i get only normal users  from my secuser table i tried with somne iterations

```
def roleId=SecRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
userInstance = SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecRole(roleId).secUser
```

here i got userInstance with all users along with  adminuser now i tried to elminate adminuser from my userInstance and saved it in selectUserMap  but am getting result for sometime  and  sometimes its giving all users.   I think the sort() function not sorting the userinstansce roles please help me

```
for(int i=0;i<userInstance.size();i++) 
{
    println( "am in loop "+i+userInstance[i].username+"roles"+userInstance[i].getAuthorities())
    def x=(userInstance[i].getAuthorities().sort())

    for(a in x )
    {   //println(a.getAuthority()) 
        if((a.getAuthority() == use))
            abc=true
        else
            abc=false
        if((a.getAuthority() == adm))
        {
            println("break")
            break;
        }
        abc=(abc && (a.getAuthority() == use))
        if(abc)
        {   
            println("am in true if  ")
            selectUserMap.add(j,userInstance[i])
            j=j+1
        }
        else  
        {           
            println("am in else")
        }

    }

}
println("==============all users "+selectUserMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that would help is to use hierarchical roles - see section "14 Hierarchical Roles" at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ - and then you wouldn't grant `ROLE_USER` to anyone but "real" users. If you define your hierarchy like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
   ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
   ROLE_DOCTOR > ROLE_USER
   ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_DOCTOR
'''
```

then you don't need to explicitly grant `ROLE_USER` in the database to either a doctor or an admin, but the role will be inferred as granted. Then your original query will work:

```
def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
def usersWithUserRole = SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecRole(userRole).secUser
```

If you can't or don't want to do this, then you should use a proper database query. It's extremely and unnecessarily expensive to load every user and every user's roles from the database and filter them out in your application. Use this HQL query:

```
def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
def users = SecUserSecRole.executeQuery(
   'select u from SecUser u where ' +
   '(select count(ur.user) from SecUserSecRole ur where ur.user=u)=1 and ' +
   '(:r in (select ur.role from SecUserSecRole ur where ur.user=u))',
   [r: userRole])
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you've choosen really complicated way, can understand your algorhitm :( Maybe this is enough:

```
List selectUserList = userInstance.findAll {
   List roles = it.authorities*.authority
   return roles.contains('ROLE_USER') && !roles.contains('ROLE_ADMIN')
}
```

I guess you can build `selectUserMap` from this `selectUserList` list (can't understand where you get `j`)

PS maybe it's better to rename `userInstance` to `userInstances`, because it's a list actually, not one  instance?

Comment: This is clearner but still way too expensive since you're loading _every_ user instance from the database just to filter them client-side.